# Morris charts different preUnits

Tags: morris.js

Is it possible to have different preUnits for Morris Line chart?

Here is my javascript:

```
Morris.Line({
    element: 'payment_chart',
    data: json.data,
    xkey: 'm',
    ykeys: json.label,
    labels: json.label,
    parseTime: false,
    preUnits: "$",
    smooth: true,
    resize: true
});
```

I have just two lines, one represents Dollar value, the other quantity. My tooltip looks like:

```
April
Sales: $3
Amount: $249.99
```

What I  would like to do is remove dollar sign from sales.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No you can't have different `preUnits` for Morris Line chart:

> preUnits: Set to a string value (eg: '$') to add a label prefix all y-labels.

But you can set the `hoverCallback` function to do the job:

```js
Morris.Line({
  element: 'payment_chart',
  data: [
    { y: '2006', a: 100, b: 90 },
    { y: '2007', a: 75, b: 65 },
    { y: '2008', a: 50, b: 40 },
    { y: '2009', a: 75, b: 65 },
    { y: '2010', a: 50, b: 40 },
    { y: '2011', a: 75, b: 65 },
    { y: '2012', a: 100, b: 90 }
  ],
  xkey: 'y',
  ykeys: ['a', 'b'],
  labels: ['Sales', 'Amount'],
  parseTime: false,
  preUnits: "$",
  smooth: true,
  resize: true,
  hoverCallback: function (index, options, content, row) {
    var indexAmount = 2;
    var txtToReplace = $(content)[indexAmount].textContent;
    return content.replace(txtToReplace, txtToReplace.replace(options.preUnits, ""));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="payment_chart"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This works perfect. I have accepted your answer.